# How can I delete all emails in a Postgres table that differ only by whitespace?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a PostgreSQL `users` table, where one of the columns is `email`. Our problem is that some users have entered the same email in two ways by mistake, that differ only by whitespace, e.g. "me@xample.com" and " me@example.com". I would like to delete all the rows that have such an email with whitespace.

Here is the query I want to use:

```
DELETE FROM ONLY users
WHERE id IN (
  SELECT users1.id
  FROM users AS users1, users AS users2
  WHERE users1.id != users2.id
      AND trim(both from users1.email) = users2.email)
```

Unfortunately this query is very slow (O(n^2) I believe because of the cross-join), and I really need a way to speed it up so we don't bog down our database.

Comment: You don't want to keep *one* of the emails?

Comment: No I do, I want to keep the one without white-space. I believe the query correctly does this?

Answer (score 1):

To begin with, you can use a correlated subquery.  But, I think you should approach this using window functions:

```
DELETE FROM ONLY users u
    FROM (SELECT u2.*,
                 ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY trim(both from u2.email) ORDER BY LENGTH(u2.email) ASC) as seqnum
          FROM users u2
         )
    WHERE u2.id = u.id AND seqnum > 1;
```

This deletes all but the shortest emails that are equivalent, modulo spaces.

(Note:  test this out on sample data before running it on a big table.)

Answer (score 0):

Use a self join to find out all users who have more than 1 email id with any extra characters in one of the emails (i assume there will only be spaces as extra characters). Then delete those rows from the original table.

```
delete from users
where (id, email) in (select u1.id,u1.email 
                      from users u1
                      join users u2 on u1.id = u2.id
                      where char_length(u1.email) - char_length(u2.email) >= 1)
```

Edit: The simplest way to do it is

```
delete from users
where length(trim(email)) <> length(email)
```